# How do I set up a horizontal "recent posts" widget for blogger?

Tags: javascript, blogger

(First time posting, so I hope I'm doing this right! Edit: nope, apparently I'm not OTL)

I'm looking to add a widget to my blogger blog that displays my 3 most recent posts next to each other, with a thumbnail and short preview of the content (eg. the title and first 100 characters of the post). Something that looks like [this](http://www.bloggerwidgetgenerators.com/2014/07/related-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-and-summary.html), for example, but for recent posts instead of related ones (and it doesn't necessarily have to be quite so fancy =p ).

Unfortunately, I've yet to find a template that I could make work. The closest I could get was [this](http://thbdemo.blogspot.be/p/blog-page.html). 
(I hope the code is retrievable from the blog itself, because it's almost 250 lines long and I don't quite know how I should go about sharing it. Also, I know the blog looks ugly. I just threw it together so I could include it as a reference - I'd prefer to keep my actual blog private =) ).

Problem is, whenever I adjust the parameters as instructed, something seems to break. I can't seem to add titles, dates, summaries or "read more" links, because when I try to adjust the relevant parameters, the 2nd and 3rd thumbnails just disappear.

I know some html and css, but javascript is still very new to me. I have no idea where to start to find out what the problem is, let alone fix it or start from scratch myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: added the full html of the widget - adding my blog's entire coding, or even just that of the template (just CSS and variable definitions, no widgets or anything) would take the post over the character limit, so I hope this is sufficient! If not, please bop me on the head and let me know what else is needed in order to be able to solve this.

```
<b:widget id='HTML1' locked='false' title='Recent' type='HTML'>
                              <b:widget-settings>
                                <b:widget-setting name='content'>&lt;div id=&quot;bp_recent&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;script style=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;

var postTitleOriginal,  myLink, myDiv, myImage,mySeparator;
var    main;
var float_clear=false;
var flag = 0;
function bprecentpostswiththumbnails(json) {

for (var i = 0; i &lt; numberOfPosts; i++) {
if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
var s;
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    var postTitle = entry.title.$t;
    postTitleOriginal = postTitle;
    if (isNaN(titleLength) || titleLength == 0) {
        postTitle = &#39;&#39;;

    }
    else if (postTitle.length &gt; titleLength) postTitle = postTitle.substring(0, titleLength) + &quot;...&quot;;
    var postUrl=&quot;&quot;;
    for (var k = 0; k &lt; entry.link.length; k++) {
        if (entry.link[k].rel == &#39;replies&#39; &amp;&amp; entry.link[k].type == &#39;text/html&#39;) {
            var commentText = entry.link[k].title;
            var commentUrl = entry.link[k].href;
        }
        if (entry.link[k].rel == &#39;alternate&#39;) {
            postUrl = entry.link[k].href;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (showThumbs == true) {
        var thumbUrl = &quot;&quot;;
        try {
            thumbUrl = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
            thumbUrl = thumbUrl.replace(&quot;/s72-c/&quot;,&quot;/s&quot;+imgDim+&quot;-c/&quot;);
        } catch (error) {
            if (&quot;content&quot; in entry) s = entry.content.$t; else s=&quot;&quot;;
            if (thumbUrl == &quot;&quot; &amp;&amp; mediaThumbsOnly == false) {
                 regex = /http\:\/\/www\.youtube(-nocookie){0,1}\.com\/(v){0,1}(embed){0,1}\/(([^&quot;&amp;?&#39; ]*))/;
                videoIds = s.match(regex);
                if (videoIds != null) {
                    videoId = videoIds[4];
                }
                if (videoIds != null &amp;&amp; videoId != null) thumbUrl = &quot;http://img.youtube.com/vi/&quot; + videoId + &quot;/2.jpg&quot;
            }
            if (thumbUrl == &quot;&quot; &amp;&amp; mediaThumbsOnly == false) {
                a = s.indexOf(&quot;&lt;img&quot;);
                b = s.indexOf(&quot;src=\&quot;&quot;, a);
                c = s.indexOf(&quot;\&quot;&quot;, b + 5);
                d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
                if ((a != -1) &amp;&amp; (b != -1) &amp;&amp; (c != -1) &amp;&amp; (d != &quot;&quot;)) thumbUrl = d;

            }

        }
        if(thumbUrl.indexOf(&quot;static.flickr.com&quot;)!=-1) {thumbUrl= thumbUrl.replace(&quot;_b_t.jpg&quot;,&quot;_s.jpg&quot;);thumbUrl= thumbUrl.replace(&quot;_m_t.jpg&quot;,&quot;_s.jpg&quot;);thumbUrl= thumbUrl.replace(&quot;_s_t.jpg&quot;,&quot;_s.jpg&quot;);
        thumbUrl= thumbUrl.replace(&quot;_b.jpg&quot;,&quot;_s.jpg&quot;);thumbUrl= thumbUrl.replace(&quot;_m.jpg&quot;,&quot;_s.jpg&quot;);}
        if (thumbUrl == &quot;&quot; &amp;&amp; showNoImage == true) 
        {
        thumbUrl = &quot;http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-erTXCq61ULM/TmHYAQBZ0GI/AAAAAAAACCs/6cBX54Dn6Gs/s72-c/default.png&quot;;
        try{if(defaultImage!=&quot;&quot;) thumbUrl=defaultImage;}catch(error){}
        thumbUrl = thumbUrl.replace(&quot;/s72-c/&quot;,&quot;/s&quot;+imgDim+&quot;-c/&quot;);
        }
    } 
    if (showPostDate == true) {
        var postdate = entry.published.$t;
        var cdyear = postdate.substring(0, 4);
        var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5, 7);
        var cdday = postdate.substring(8, 10);
        var monthnames = new Array();
        monthnames[1] = &quot;Jan&quot;;
        monthnames[2] = &quot;Feb&quot;;
        monthnames[3] = &quot;Mar&quot;;
        monthnames[4] = &quot;Apr&quot;;
        monthnames[5] = &quot;May&quot;;
        monthnames[6] = &quot;Jun&quot;;
        monthnames[7] = &quot;Jul&quot;;
        monthnames[8] = &quot;Aug&quot;;
        monthnames[9] = &quot;Sep&quot;;
        monthnames[10] = &quot;Oct&quot;;
        monthnames[11] = &quot;Nov&quot;;
        monthnames[12] = &quot;Dec&quot;;
    } 
    code = &quot;&quot;;
        main = document.getElementById(&#39;bp_recent&#39;);
        myDiv = document.createElement(&#39;div&#39;);
        myDiv.setAttribute(&quot;class&quot;, &quot;bp_item_title&quot;);
        myLink = createLink(postUrl,&quot;_top&quot;,postTitleOriginal)
        if(main.innerHTML!=&quot;&quot;){
        mySeparator = createDiv(&quot;bp_recent_separator&quot;);
        main.appendChild(mySeparator)
        }
        if(postTitle != &#39;&#39;){myDiv.appendChild(myLink);}
        main.appendChild(myDiv);if(postTitle != &#39;&#39;)myLink.innerHTML = postTitle;





    if (showThumbs == true &amp;&amp; thumbUrl != &quot;&quot;) {
        myImage = document.createElement(&#39;img&#39;);
        myImage.setAttribute(&quot;src&quot;, thumbUrl);
        if(imgFloat!=&quot;none&quot;)
        {
        float_clear=true;
        myImage.style.cssFloat=imgFloat;
        myImage.style.styleFloat=imgFloat;
        }
      try{if(myMargin!=0)myImage.style.margin = myMargin+&quot;px&quot;;} catch(error){}
        myImage.setAttribute(&quot;alt&quot;, postTitleOriginal);
        myImage.setAttribute(&quot;width&quot;, imgDim);
        myImage.setAttribute(&quot;height&quot;, imgDim);
        myLink = document.createElement(&#39;a&#39;);
        myLink.setAttribute(&quot;href&quot;, postUrl+&quot;?utm_source=bp_recent&amp;utm-medium=gadget&amp;utm_campaign=bp_recent&quot;);
        myLink.setAttribute(&quot;target&quot;, &quot;_top&quot;);
        myLink.setAttribute(&quot;title&quot;, postTitleOriginal);
        myLink.appendChild(myImage);

        myDiv = document.createElement(&#39;div&#39;);
        myDiv.setAttribute(&quot;class&quot;, &quot;bp_item_thumb&quot;);
        myDiv.appendChild(myLink);
        main.appendChild(myDiv);
    }

 try {
        if (&quot;content&quot; in entry) {
            var postContent = entry.content.$t;
        }
        else if (&quot;summary&quot; in entry) {
            var postContent = entry.summary.$t;
        }
        else var postContent = &quot;&quot;;
        var re = /&lt;\S[^&gt;]*&gt;/g;
        postContent = postContent.replace(re, &quot;&quot;);


        if (showSummary == true) {
            myDiv = createDiv(&quot;bp_item_summary&quot;);
                if (postContent.length &lt; summaryLength) {myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(postContent));}
            else {
                postContent = postContent.substring(0, summaryLength);
                var quoteEnd = postContent.lastIndexOf(&quot; &quot;);
                postContent = postContent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
                myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(postContent + &#39;...&#39;));
            }

            main.appendChild(myDiv);
        }
    } //end try
    catch (error) {}

    myDiv =  createDiv(&quot;bp_item_meta&quot;);
    myDiv.style.clear=&quot;both&quot;;
    myDiv.style.marginBottom=&quot;4px&quot;;


    if (showPostDate == true) {
        myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth, 10)] + &#39;-&#39; + cdday + &#39;-&#39; + cdyear));
        flag = 1;
    }

    if (showCommentCount == true) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(&quot; | &quot;));
        }
        if (commentText == &#39;1 Comments&#39;) commentText = &#39;1 Comment&#39;;
        if (commentText == &#39;0 Comments&#39;) commentText = &#39;No Comments&#39;;
        var myLink = createLink(commentUrl,&quot;_top&quot;,commentText + &quot; on &quot; + postTitleOriginal)
        myDiv.appendChild(myLink);
        myLink.innerHTML=commentText;
        flag = 1;;
    }

    if (showReadMore == true) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(&quot; | &quot;));
        }
        var myLink = createLink(postUrl,&quot;_top&quot;,postTitleOriginal)
        myDiv.appendChild(myLink);
        myLink.innerHTML = readMore+&quot; &amp;raquo;&quot;;
        flag = 1;;
    }



    if (flag == 1) main.appendChild(myDiv);

}

if(float_clear==true &amp;&amp; imgFloat!=&quot;none&quot;)
{
myDiv = createDiv(&quot;bp_clear_float&quot;);
myDiv.style.clear=imgFloat;
main.appendChild(myDiv);
}
document.getElementById(&quot;bp_recent_link&quot;).style.backgroundImage=&quot;url(&#39;http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-H8WPIh3wjr4/TmHnuo9tnnI/AAAAAAAACDE/_yuVqfb1HAk/blogger-widgets.png&#39;)&quot;;
document.getElementById(&quot;bp_recent_link&quot;).style.backgroundRepeat=&quot;no-repeat&quot;;
try{
if(myMargin!=0 &amp;&amp; imgFloat==&quot;left&quot; &amp;&amp; flag==0) document.getElementById(&quot;bp_recent_link&quot;).style.marginLeft = myMargin+&quot;px&quot;;
} catch(error){}
}


function createDiv(className)
{
var myDiv = document.createElement(&#39;div&#39;);
myDiv.setAttribute(&quot;class&quot;, className);
return myDiv;
}


function createLink(href,target,title)
{

var myLink = document.createElement(&#39;a&#39;);
        if(href.substring(href.length-13,href.length)==&quot;#comment-form&quot;) {href= href.substring(0,href.length-13)+&quot;?utm_source=bp_recent&amp;utm-medium=gadget&amp;utm_campaign=bp_recent&quot;+&quot;#comment-form&quot;;myLink.setAttribute(&quot;href&quot;, href);}
        else myLink.setAttribute(&quot;href&quot;, href+&quot;?utm_source=BP_recent&amp;utm-medium=gadget&amp;utm_campaign=bp_recent&quot;);
        myLink.setAttribute(&quot;target&quot;, target);
        myLink.setAttribute(&quot;title&quot;, title);
        return myLink;
}



&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;script style=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
var numberOfPosts = 3;
var showPostDate = true;
var showSummary = true;
var titleLength = 0;
var showCommentCount = false;
var showThumbs = true;
var showNoImage = true;
var imgDim = 180;
var imgFloat = &quot;left&quot;;
var myMargin = 5;
var mediaThumbsOnly = true;
var showReadMore = true;
&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;script src=&quot;http://thbdemo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=5&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=bprecentpostswiththumbnails&quot;&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;</b:widget-setting>
                              </b:widget-settings>
                              <b:includable id='main'>
  <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
    <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
  </b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <data:content/>
  </div>

  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

As mentioned above, I can't include my entire blog's coding, since that would take this post over the character limit, but I figure the variable definitions might be useful/needed too, so I'll include that part below (fyi: yes, the variables are defined before the widgets):

```
/* Variable definitions
====================
<Variable name="keycolor" description="Main Color" type="color" default="#66bbdd" value="#cc8366"/>
<Group description="Page Text" selector="body">
<Variable name="body.font" description="Font" type="font"
default="normal normal 12px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"/>
<Variable name="body.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color" default="#222222" value="#222222"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Backgrounds" selector=".body-fauxcolumns-outer">
<Variable name="body.background.color" description="Outer Background" type="color" default="#66bbdd" value="#51313a"/>
<Variable name="content.background.color" description="Main Background" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#fff0ee"/>
<Variable name="header.background.color" description="Header Background" type="color" default="transparent" value="#cc8366"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Links" selector=".main-outer">
<Variable name="link.color" description="Link Color" type="color" default="#2288bb" value="#990019"/>
<Variable name="link.visited.color" description="Visited Color" type="color" default="#888888" value="#888888"/>
<Variable name="link.hover.color" description="Hover Color" type="color" default="#33aaff" value="#ff0066"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Blog Title" selector=".header h1">
<Variable name="header.font" description="Font" type="font"
default="normal normal 60px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 40px Fontdiner Swanky"/>
<Variable name="header.text.color" description="Title Color" type="color" default="#3399bb"  value="#ffffff"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Blog Description" selector=".header .description">
<Variable name="description.text.color" description="Description Color" type="color"
default="#777777"  value="#ffffff"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Tabs Text" selector=".tabs-inner .widget li a">
<Variable name="tabs.font" description="Font" type="font"
default="normal normal 14px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 16px Calibri"/>
<Variable name="tabs.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color" default="#999999" value="#997777"/>
<Variable name="tabs.selected.text.color" description="Selected Color" type="color" default="#000000" value="#000000"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Tabs Background" selector=".tabs-outer .PageList">
<Variable name="tabs.background.color" description="Background Color" type="color" default="#f5f5f5" value="#ffeeee"/>
<Variable name="tabs.selected.background.color" description="Selected Color" type="color" default="#eeeeee" value="#fff0ee"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Post Title" selector="h3.post-title, .comments h4">
<Variable name="post.title.font" description="Font" type="font"
default="normal normal 22px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 24px Georgia, Utopia, &#39;Palatino Linotype&#39;, Palatino, serif"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Date Header" selector=".date-header">
<Variable name="date.header.color" description="Text Color" type="color"
default="$(body.text.color)" value="#222222"/>
<Variable name="date.header.background.color" description="Background Color" type="color"
default="transparent" value="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"/>
<Variable name="date.header.font" description="Text Font" type="font"
default="normal bold 11px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal bold 12px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif"/>
<Variable name="date.header.padding" description="Date Header Padding" type="string" default="inherit" value="inherit"/>
<Variable name="date.header.letterspacing" description="Date Header Letter Spacing" type="string" default="inherit" value="inherit"/>
<Variable name="date.header.margin" description="Date Header Margin" type="string" default="inherit" value="inherit"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Post Footer" selector=".post-footer">
<Variable name="post.footer.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color" default="#666666" value="#665c55"/>
<Variable name="post.footer.background.color" description="Background Color" type="color"
default="#f9f9f9" value="#eee0dd"/>
<Variable name="post.footer.border.color" description="Shadow Color" type="color" default="#eeeeee" value="#eeeeee"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Gadgets" selector="h2">
<Variable name="widget.title.font" description="Title Font" type="font"
default="normal bold 11px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal bold 12px Georgia, Utopia, &#39;Palatino Linotype&#39;, Palatino, serif"/>
<Variable name="widget.title.text.color" description="Title Color" type="color" default="#000000" value="#000000"/>
<Variable name="widget.alternate.text.color" description="Alternate Color" type="color" default="#999999" value="#999999"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Images" selector=".main-inner">
<Variable name="image.background.color" description="Background Color" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#ffffff"/>
<Variable name="image.border.color" description="Border Color" type="color" default="#eeeeee" value="#eeeeee"/>
<Variable name="image.text.color" description="Caption Text Color" type="color" default="$(body.text.color)" value="#222222"/>
</Group>
<Group description="Accents" selector=".content-inner">
<Variable name="body.rule.color" description="Separator Line Color" type="color" default="#eeeeee" value="#eedddd"/>
<Variable name="tabs.border.color" description="Tabs Border Color" type="color" default="$(body.rule.color)" value="#eee5dd"/>
</Group>
<Variable name="body.background" description="Body Background" type="background"
color="$(body.background.color)" default="$(color) none repeat scroll top left" value="$(color) none no-repeat scroll center center"/>
<Variable name="body.background.override" description="Body Background Override" type="string" default="" value=""/>
<Variable name="body.background.gradient.cap" description="Body Gradient Cap" type="url"
default="url(https://resources.blogblog.com/blogblog/data/1kt/simple/gradients_light.png)" value="none"/>
<Variable name="body.background.gradient.tile" description="Body Gradient Tile" type="url"
default="url(https://resources.blogblog.com/blogblog/data/1kt/simple/body_gradient_tile_light.png)" value="none"/>
<Variable name="content.background.color.selector" description="Content Background Color Selector" type="string" default=".content-inner" value=".content-inner"/>
<Variable name="content.padding" description="Content Padding" type="length" default="10px" min="0" max="100px" value="10px"/>
<Variable name="content.padding.horizontal" description="Content Horizontal Padding" type="length" default="$(content.padding)" min="0" max="100px" value="10px"/>
<Variable name="content.shadow.spread" description="Content Shadow Spread" type="length" default="40px" min="0" max="100px" value="40px"/>
<Variable name="content.shadow.spread.webkit" description="Content Shadow Spread (WebKit)" type="length" default="5px" min="0" max="100px" value="5px"/>
<Variable name="content.shadow.spread.ie" description="Content Shadow Spread (IE)" type="length" default="10px" min="0" max="100px" value="10px"/>
<Variable name="main.border.width" description="Main Border Width" type="length" default="0" min="0" max="10px" value="0"/>
<Variable name="header.background.gradient" description="Header Gradient" type="url" default="none" value="url(https://www.blogblog.com/1kt/simple/gradients_light.png)"/>
<Variable name="header.shadow.offset.left" description="Header Shadow Offset Left" type="length" default="-1px" min="-50px" max="50px" value="1px"/>
<Variable name="header.shadow.offset.top" description="Header Shadow Offset Top" type="length" default="-1px" min="-50px" max="50px" value="2px"/>
<Variable name="header.shadow.spread" description="Header Shadow Spread" type="length" default="1px" min="0" max="100px" value="3px"/>
<Variable name="header.padding" description="Header Padding" type="length" default="30px" min="0" max="100px" value="30px"/>
<Variable name="header.border.size" description="Header Border Size" type="length" default="1px" min="0" max="10px" value="0"/>
<Variable name="header.bottom.border.size" description="Header Bottom Border Size" type="length" default="$(header.border.size)" min="0" max="10px" value="0"/>
<Variable name="header.border.horizontalsize" description="Header Horizontal Border Size" type="length" default="0" min="0" max="10px" value="0"/>
<Variable name="description.text.size" description="Description Text Size" type="string" default="140%" value="140%"/>
<Variable name="tabs.margin.top" description="Tabs Margin Top" type="length" default="0" min="0" max="100px" value="0"/>
<Variable name="tabs.margin.side" description="Tabs Side Margin" type="length" default="30px" min="0" max="100px" value="30px"/>
<Variable name="tabs.background.gradient" description="Tabs Background Gradient" type="url"
default="url(https://resources.blogblog.com/blogblog/data/1kt/simple/gradients_light.png)" value="none"/>
<Variable name="tabs.border.width" description="Tabs Border Width" type="length" default="1px" min="0" max="10px" value="1px"/>
<Variable name="tabs.bevel.border.width" description="Tabs Bevel Border Width" type="length" default="1px" min="0" max="10px" value="1px"/>
<Variable name="post.margin.bottom" description="Post Bottom Margin" type="length" default="25px" min="0" max="100px" value="25px"/>
<Variable name="image.border.small.size" description="Image Border Small Size" type="length" default="2px" min="0" max="10px" value="2px"/>
<Variable name="image.border.large.size" description="Image Border Large Size" type="length" default="5px" min="0" max="10px" value="5px"/>
<Variable name="page.width.selector" description="Page Width Selector" type="string" default=".region-inner" value=".region-inner"/>
<Variable name="page.width" description="Page Width" type="string" default="auto" value="auto"/>
<Variable name="main.section.margin" description="Main Section Margin" type="length" default="15px" max="100px" value="15px"/>
<Variable name="main.padding" description="Main Padding" type="length" default="15px" min="0" max="100px" value="15px"/>
<Variable name="main.padding.top" description="Main Padding Top" type="length" default="30px" min="0" max="100px" value="30px"/>
<Variable name="main.padding.bottom" description="Main Padding Bottom" type="length" default="30px" min="0" max="100px" value="30px"/>
<Variable name="paging.background"
color="$(content.background.color)"
description="Background of blog paging area" type="background"
default="transparent none no-repeat scroll top center" value="transparent none no-repeat scroll top center"/>
<Variable name="footer.bevel" description="Bevel border length of footer" type="length" default="0" min="0" max="10px" value="0"/>
<Variable name="mobile.background.overlay" description="Mobile Background Overlay" type="string"
default="transparent none repeat scroll top left" value="transparent none repeat scroll top left"/>
<Variable name="mobile.background.size" description="Mobile Background Size" type="string" default="auto" value="auto"/>
<Variable name="mobile.button.color" description="Mobile Button Color" type="color" default="#ffffff"  value="#ffffff"/>
<Variable name="startSide" description="Side where text starts in blog language" type="automatic" default="left"/>
<Variable name="endSide" description="Side where text ends in blog language" type="automatic" default="right"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! please post your html,css and js so we can try help you out.

Comment: Thanks! Added the code, apologies for not including it from the getgo =)

Comment: Posting a question - you're doing it wrong xD please supply the code including html, where we can see the actual problem. Not on external site but all relevant code should be here. If we can't reproduce your problem based on supplied code we can't help.

Comment: Seems my first question should've been "how to properly post a question" OTL. I apologize for my floundering, I figured since the tutorial I followed only included that part of the coding (which is what you need to paste in a html/javascript gadget for blogger), posting just that would've been enough. I've now tried to include as much relevant coding as possible, but the character limit keeps me from including the entire coding. Please let me know if there's still vital parts missing, though!